# Connecting to Remote MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, amazon-web-services, aws-opsworks

I installed mongodb on my server (AWS) and I have an Application that's supposed to connect to this server and use the mongodb for my messaging. I ran the `db._adminCommand( {getCmdLineOpts: 1})` command and go the following output, which shows the mongodb configuration:

```
{
        "argv" : [
                "/usr/bin/mongod",
                "--config",
                "/etc/mongod.conf"
        ],
        "parsed" : {
                "config" : "/etc/mongod.conf",
                "net" : {
                        "bindIp" : "0.0.0.0",
                        "port" : 27017
                },
                "storage" : {
                        "dbPath" : "/var/lib/mongodb",
                        "journal" : {
                                "enabled" : true
                        }
                },
                "systemLog" : {
                        "destination" : "file",
                        "logAppend" : true,
                        "path" : "/var/log/mongodb/mongod.log"
                }
        },
        "ok" : 1
}
```

QUESTION: 
Please how do I configure the server and Opsworks so that my app can establish communication with the mongodb service running on the server? Please any pointers will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Your mongodb config looks like it is prepared to accept connections. What happens when your application tries to connect in the normal way?

Comment: I get no feedback, no errors, no warnings nothing. I try this using postman

Comment: [Postman](https://www.getpostman.com/), the API testing tool?